# How to apply dynamic data in React Native share

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For my recipe app, I want to enable users to share recipes with their friends. For this, I'm using the official React Native share function. I'm trying to pass props to the message and title, without any success. Here's the code I'm using for sharing.

```
 onShare = async () => {
// const result = await
const { caption } = this.props.section;
Share.share(
  {
    message: caption,
    title: "{section.caption}"
  },
  {
    excludedActivityTypes: [
      // 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToWeibo',
      // 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.Print',
      // 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.CopyToPasteboard',
      // 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.AssignToContact',
      // 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.SaveToCameraRoll',
      // 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.AddToReadingList',
      // 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFlickr',
      // 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToVimeo',
      // 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTencentWeibo',
      "com.apple.UIKit.activity.AirDrop"
      // 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.OpenInIBooks',
      // 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.MarkupAsPDF',
      // 'com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension',
      // 'com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension',
      // 'com.apple.mobileslideshow.StreamShareService',
      // 'com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension',
      // 'pinterest.ShareExtension',
      // 'com.google.GooglePlus.ShareExtension',
      // 'com.tumblr.tumblr.Share-With-Tumblr',
      // 'net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension', //WhatsApp
    ]
  }
);
```

};

The way data is loaded into this page is via {section.XXX}. Example:

```
 <Caption style={styles.Caption}>{section.caption}</Caption>
```

This is how I trigger the 'onShare' func.

```
<Button title="Share recipe" onPress={this.onShare} />
```

I hope someone can help me with this challenge. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is your props coming from redux? If not, what is the output of this.props.section on your onShare function? Was it undefined?

Comment: props are coming from redux indeed! And passed via react navigation. The response was Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.section.caption')

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code, the first one is string interpolation which is unnecessary and wrongly executed and the second is that you're referencing an inexistant prop. You're saying in a comment that `this.props.section` is undefined, that's because the data seems to be passed via the special `children` prop.

```js
onShare = () => {
    const { children } = this.props;

    if (typeof children !== "string") {
        return;
    }

    Share.share({
        message: children,
        title: children
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm receiving the following error: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.section.caption')". So, I'm afraid I'm not passing the props right to that function. I'm using the following code below render:
`render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const section = navigation.getParam("section");
    const props = this.props`

Comment: Precisely, you're passing `section.caption` into the `children` prop of the `Caption` component. Refer to my code for the correct way to use this value.

Comment: I don't get any errors! But it doesn't show the 'section.caption' data either. How can I specifically dynamic this prop within your code example? Thanks for all the effort!!

Comment: Simply copy my code, you need to access the `children` prop. You're passing the value of `section.caption` *in the parent*, the child component needs to access it using the `children` prop.

Comment: The data get passed and is also reflected in the UI. However, If I click on the button it doesn't open the share modal. I feel I'm almost there. This is the code for the button:
`<Button
          title={section.caption}
          message={section.caption}
          onPress={this.onShare}
        />`